# how to make everything open on external monitor

Tags: macos, display, big-sur

I m using MBP with a external screen. I want everything I open to open up in external monitor as I got really bad neck pain, so If I look down at laptop screen I can't do anything else due to pain.

ATM I can drag the window of application on external monitor but the contextual menu remains on laptop as well as dock.

How can I make sure that external screen is used or/and the laptop screen isn't used.

Comment: I close the laptop, using an external keyboard and mouse - works fine.

Comment: Or set the external monitor as the primary monitor in System Preferences

Comment: @SolarMike yes but I don't have ext. keyboard. so my mac would be only mac and trackpad

Comment: @nohillside how I tried to find but couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351) which describes how to set the external monitor as your primary display.

Alternatively you can attach an external keyboard/mouse and just close your laptop.